# Launch teams meeting on android phone from my own app

Tags: android, android-intent

suppose i have installed the Microsoft teams app on my android phone, and in my own app i got the teams meeting link like this(basically i can use this link to join the meeting from laptop):

```html
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_M2JlOTk1YTQtOTc2YS00Y2EwLTkxNzYtMmNmYTgxYjA2ZTRm%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2272f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22e7d6f57c-6d9d-4605-8128-14c46a94c498%22%7d
```

Right now i'd like to launch the teams app from my app and join the meeting directly, is it possible for me to change the link a little bit(the URL scheme) as below, launch teams and join the meeting with a intent:

```html
msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_M2JlOTk1YTQtOTc2YS00Y2EwLTkxNzYtMmNmYTgxYjA2ZTRm%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2272f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22e7d6f57c-6d9d-4605-8128-14c46a94c498%22%7d
```

Comment: Have you tried using the normal url?

Comment: if i open the https link above directly in the browser, it will launch the teams app and join the meeting, but i want to use the intent to launch the teams app and join the meeting directly from my app instead, i haven't tried this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

1. selecting link,
2. share-to -> Teams?

It worked for me as guest to a conversation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).